# The desktop image moved to one side

Tags: display, .desktop, gpu-driver

Question update: The original install was fine. Later, the whole desktop image shifted to the right. I didn't change anything. If I boot into Ubuntu's "fail safe graphic mode," the desktop display is positioned normally. Can someone tell me how to re-install the display code/drivers?

I'm booting to a full Ubuntu 14.04 installation on a USB thumb drive.

There are similar, but not identical, post showing these fixes:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper
debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

I would like to just re-install the original Ubuntu 14.04 video code/driver. Will any of the suggestions above do that?

Comment: You might want to check your monitor settings. See if it has an auto adjust button.

Comment: If you're monitor has those hard buttons, then use them. What monitor do you own?

Comment: My monitor is a Samsung TV. Its controls are via on-screen menu.

Comment: When I boot to Windows, on the hard drive; or, when I use the TV, the display is fine. I only see the issue when I boot to Ubuntu (on a bootable thumb drive).

Comment: I'm looking through the screen controls. I don't see a way to move the whole display.

Comment: At the first Ubuntu boot window I selected:  
--Advanced options for Ubuntu.Ubuntu,with Linux 4.2.0-34 --generic (recovery mode).

--failsafex Run in fail safe graphic mode.

--Run in low-graphic mode for just one session.

  **When the desktop loaded the display issue was resolved.** The desktop image was centered in the display. 

*Would this help anyone that may be able to help?*

Comment: The display was getting worse. Some windows were flickering. I gave up and installed a new version of Ubuntu. No more display problems. So it was an OS display code issue.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and installed a new version of Ubuntu. No more display problems. So it was an OS display code/driver issue.